# AWS Rekognition error: Chunk video failed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, video, ffmpeg, amazon-rekognition

I'm using and launching Amazon Rekognition on my videos uploaded into my S3 with python. Every video is converted with FFMPEG with `AAC` Audio Codec and `H264` Video Codec and then given to Rekognition. Videos are always fine, the problem is that only 60-70% of videos are processed successfully, while the rest of videos goes into error. In particular, inside the JSON returned from Rekognition:

```
{'JobId': '<id of my job>', 'Status': 'FAILED', 'API': 'StartFaceDetection', 'Message': 'Chunk video failed: Only 1 I-frames found in video', 'Timestamp': 1655118632996, 'Video': {'S3ObjectName': '<my video inside S3>', 'S3Bucket': '<my S3>'}, 'ErrorCode': 'VideoNotDecodable'}
```

As you can see, I get an error `"Chunk video failed: only 1 I-Frames found in video"`. Honestly I don't know what is that, but the fact that I convert every video in the same way, but Rekognition fails only with some, makes me crazy. Googling was not helpful, hope you can tell me what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: when you change video codec during the conversion, the I-Frames get resetted. 90% of my converted videos had only 1 I-Frame, that's why AWS Rekognition used to fail. I just changed FFMPEG parameters to add key-frames during the conversion.

From:

```
-c:a aac -c:v libx264
```

To:

```
-c:a aac -c:v libx264 -force_key_frames source -x264-params keyint=35:scenecut=0
```

Now I get 10-20 key-frames in my videos, so rekognition never fails.